# product of normal and lognormal variates

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, lognormal-distribution

If x and y are uncorrelated normal variates, x*exp(y) will have a symmetric unimodal distribution with positive excess kurtosis. Has this distribution been named and studied?

Comment: Standard normals $N(0,1)$ or general Normals $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$? And if the latter, do you wish to assume they share the same means and variances or not?

Comment: I think even the simple case of x = N(0,1) and y = N(0,ysd^2) is interesting. Obviously as ysd approaches zero the product x*exp(y) approaches normality, but has the case of ysd >= 1 been studied?

Answer (score 3):

Minxian Yang terms the distribution of x*exp(y) the normal log-normal mixture and studies its properties in the working paper "[Normal Log-normal Mixture: Leptokurtosis, Skewness and Applications](http://fmwww.bc.edu/RePEc/esAUSM04/up.21034.1077779387.pdf)". He allows for x and y to be correlated.

Comment: Can you expand on your answer a little. please? Can you say anything about its properties? Could you give a complete reference? Out of curiosity, did you find this after you posted? (It's perfectly valid to post a question you already have an answer to, and to answer your own question, so it doesn't matter either way, but my curiosity is biting me.)