# What is the pdf of a normal distribution divided by the square root of a log-normal over n?

Tags: normal-distribution, density-function, lognormal-distribution, t-distribution

We know that if $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, $W \sim \chi^2(n)$ and are independently distributed, then the variable $Y = \frac{Z}{\sqrt{W/n}}$ follows a $t$-distribution with degrees of freedom $n$. Now I am wondering, if $X$ is a log-normal like $X \sim \log\mathcal{N}(a,b)$ and is independent from $Z$, what is  $Y = \frac{Z}{\sqrt{X/n}}$?

I know there is this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/507175/102655), but it shows the pdf of $Y = \frac{Z}{X}$. Can anyone build on this to answer my question. Thank you!

Comment: I indicated the answer in comments to your previous, now-deleted question.  That's why we prefer you edit unanswered questions rather than post new ones.

Comment: Thank for the advices @whuber!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can manipulate $Y$ to help us here. First note we can re-write $Y$ as

$$Y = \frac{n^{1/2}Z}{X^{1/2}}$$
and because $Z\sim N(0,1)$ then $n^{1/2}Z \sim  N(0, n)$.

Now we know $X \sim \log N(a, b)$. By the definition of the log-normal we have $\log(X) \sim N(a, b)$. Using standard log laws we have $\log(X^{1/2}) = \frac{1}{2} \log(X)$ thus $\log(X^{1/2}) \sim N(\frac{a}{2}, \frac{b}{4})$.

So by the definition of the log-Normal we have $\sqrt{X} \sim \log N(\frac{a}{2}, \frac{b}{4})$.

So because $Y$ can actually be expressed as the ratio of a Normal RV and a log-Normal RV you can simply apply the result from the referenced question using the above representation of $Y$.

Comment: Just an addendum to above answer: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{X}}$ is also *log-normal*.
So $Y$ is a *product* of independent normal and log-normal variables. This [SE answer][2] points to [this study](http://fmwww.bc.edu/RePEc/esAUSM04/up.21034.1077779387.pdf) of *normal log-normal mixtures* (author's term for $e^{1/2\eta}\epsilon$ with $\eta$ and $\epsilon$ correlated normal variables). [2]: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/96623/40256

Comment: @jken Are you sure $b$ is not divided $2$ rather than $4$? Simulations and other resources seems to be suggesting that. Also, will your answer works even if $Z$ is not standard? I would assume, but just want to be sure. Thank you,

Comment: Note $b/4$ is the variance not the standard deviation. A standard result is $var(aX) = a^2 var(X)$ so $b$ turns into $(1/2)^2b = b/4$. Have you taken $b$ to be the standard deviation?

Comment: Yes I have. Thank you for the informations!

Comment: @jcken, last comment : if you don't mind checking this related question, I would really appreciate :  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/533520/what-are-the-sampling-distributions-underlying-a-product-of-gaussian-variables